# How do I know if Excel has recovered all data with problematic content?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I downloaded an Excel created by [DataTables](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5) but when I open it I'm greeted with this ambiguous error:

[image]

I select Yes and the Excel opens with seemingly all of the data, but it's such a big spreadsheet that I can't tell if Excel recovered all data or not ("...as much as we can").

Does Excel tell you if it was unable to recover **all** data?

Comment: As it means that there is an error it can't process it can't possibly tell you how much it wasn't able to recover.

Comment: Fair point I suppose. It could at least highlight the row(s) with data it has a "problem" with.

Comment: But it might not even be related to a column. Maybe it's a data source connection or a macro. There are a lot of options what might be wrong with a file.

Comment: I had cases where large amounts turned out missing. I had other cases when nothing ever was missing after this message. So it's hit-n-miss.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't tell you clearly, and yes, you might have 'hidden' loss.
I had that often in the last decades of working with Excel, and have stopped to ever use that function.

I recommend to read such messages as *'the file is corrupted, go find your last backup, or you will rue it later'*.
Of course, if you don't have a backup, that is tough (it taught me to *have backups*). But continuing with a 'recovered' file, and finding months later that relevant data is missing, is often worse.

if the file is always generated that way, you don't have another option - take it and hope for the best. Aside from saving the result in a new file, and comparing the two with tools, there is no way to know if something was lost.

Note that **.xlsx is factually ZIP file* - simply rename it to *.ZIP, and open it, and you can analyse all the pieces of the Excel sheet separately, in multiple sub-folder and (XML-)files. Maybe you can identify the problem point and fix it manually.